# Blendability не взлетает

Tags: xaml, mvvm-light

Есть интерфейс:

```
public interface IAccount
{
    IList<AccountViewModel> GetAccountList();
}
```

Вот для дизайнтайма его реализую:

```
public class DesignAccountManagerViewModel: IAccount
{
    public IList<AccountViewModel> GetAccountList()
    {
        var people = new List<AccountViewModel>
        {
            new AccountViewModel("", "",
                new VkAccount(
                    new Uri(
                        "http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/25900000/Poke-icons-pokemon-25942511-100-100.jpg"),
                    "Пикачу")),
            new AccountViewModel("", "",
                new VkAccount(
                    new Uri(
                        "http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/3/39/007Squirtle.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/100?cb=20140328191525"),
                    "Сквирел"))
        };

        return people;
    }
}
```

Вот для рантайма:

```
public IList<AccountViewModel> GetAccountList()
{
    return  new ObservableCollection<AccountViewModel>();

    ///Здесь будет еще загрузка из сохраненных данных
}
```

Конструктор:

```
    public AccountManagerViewModel(IAccount dataService)
    {

        AccountList = new ObservableCollection<AccountViewModel>();
        var al = dataService.GetAccountList();
        //Это я уже как не извращался
        foreach (var a in al)
        {
            AccountList.Add(a);
        }  
    }
```

Регистрирую в `ViewModelLocator`:

```
            if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IAccount, DesignAccountManagerViewModel>();
        }
        else
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IAccount, AccountList>();
        }

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<AccountManagerViewModel>();
```

Прописываю в `xaml`:

```
        <cntr:AccountManagerControl DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=AccountManager}"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
```

В рантайме все работает, в дизайнере - фиг. ЧЯДНТ?

Comment: Хм. Отладка design time-поведения — та ещё задача. Я бы на вашем месте упрощал код до тех пор, пока не заработает. ну или вот вам walkhrough: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514636%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#Anchor_5

Comment: @VladD я даже уже примеры мввм лайт нашел, повторяю - не взлетает) они там простейшие) Что-то тут не чисто

Comment: Окей, а если временно не пользоваться IoC, а создавать безусловно `DesignAccountManagerVM`? Давайте попробуем ограничить список возможных проблем.